# onmouseover incorrect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I would like to hover over text ***"Me"*** and for it to pop up with ***"You"***.

```
<div class="relative"> 
<p onmouseover="document.getElementById('toolTipDiv').className='activeToolTip'"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('toolTipDiv').className='idleToolTip'">Me<p/>
<div id="toolTipDiv" class="idleToolTip">You.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: YoungSam seems forgot to response to your question. Please have a close look to my solution. It may me helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using jQuery!

your tooltipDiv should have `display: none` as CSS property, then use:

```
<p onmouseover="$('#toolTipDiv').show();"
onmouseout="$('#toolTipDiv').hide();">Me<p/>
```

if your tooltipDiv is displayed over the "Me" text then you have a problem because the onmouseout event is fired. Don't know where your toolTip is appearing!

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
<p class="me">Me</p>
<div id="activeToolTip">You</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('.me').hover(function() {
  $('#toolTipDiv').removeClass('idleToolTip').addClass('activeToolTip');
}, function(){
  $('#toolTipDiv').removeClass('activeToolTip').addClass('idleToolTip');
});
```

***OR***

For just show-hide you can do:

```
$('.me').hover(function() {
  $('#toolTipDiv').toggle()
});
```